# No response from getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to build a very small service using Apache Cordova and JavaScript, typically I'm trying to avoid JS and use ready solutions, but this question is quite unique.

My app is very simple, it checks for current coordinates (I'm using geolocation API, works very well) and it looks up the coordinates using uk-postcodes.com API and looks for matching postal code and my app should display it. For some reason I cannot make a query to uk-postcodes. My current code looks like that:

```
var url = "http://uk-postcodes.com/latlng/" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + ".json?callback=json";

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    console.log(json.postcode);
});
```

I was able to display variable URL and it was working fine so that's not a source of my problem. It looks like that (example) http://uk-postcodes.com/latlng/51.5000,0.1167.json and it works fine.

My problem sits somewhere inside .getJSON code, but I'm not experienced enough to solve and I'm not getting any errors in the console.

Comment: What does it say in the Console? Are you sure Cross Origin requests are allowed?

Comment: Why did you add `callback=json` to the URL?

Comment: You should always add a `.fail(function() { /*your error handling*/ })` to your `getJSON` otherwise you won't get the info if something went wrong.

Comment: that api isn't CORS enabled and isn't serving json unless it requires a specific callback name. Will likely need to use a proxy server or service to get the data

Comment: Try using https://crossorigin.me/http://uk-postcodes.com/latlng/... :)

Comment: @Quentin In the API description it says: "_If using JSON, add '?callback=[some function call]' to the url to return JSONP_". But none  of the listed methods serves JSONP when adding a callback parameter...

Comment: @towerofnix - **It Works!!!** You are awesome - Thank you! Feel free to add it as an answer and I will change it to solution.

Comment: @Quentin - I tried to make JSONP request, but it didn't work for some reason. I forgot to remove that bit from the code, but it didn't make any difference anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're running the request to a different not-CORS-enabled server page. You'll need to use a CORS proxy - for example, https://crossorigin.me.

Just add `https://crossorigin.me/` before you're URL and you'll be good to go:

```
url = 'https://crossorigin.me/' + url;
```